# Why my API mock patch is not working on Python?

Tags: python, api, unit-testing, patch

I'm a newbie to unit testing and mock. I have one script `get_table.py` and a function in it

```
def get_table_name(id):
    url = "https://some_api" + id
    table = requests.get(url)
    return table
```

then I created a unit testing script as follows:

```
from get_table import get_table_name
from unittest.mock import patch 

class TestFetchTable(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('get_table.get_table_name')
    def test_get_table_name(self,mock):
        mock.return_value = 'table_1'
        result = get_table_name('id1')
        self.assertEquals(result, 'table_1')

if __name__== '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The unit test is passed here but the test still ran over the actual API not the mocked API. May I know that I did wrong here?

Comment: Hi, interesting, perhaps import the base module `import get_table`, not sure...

Comment: Try to use `import get_table` and call `get_table.get_table_name` instead, as this is what you have patched. Check [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6).

Answer (score 0):

You should mock the `requests.get` method.

E.g.

`get_table.py`:

```py
import requests


def get_table_name(id):
    url = "https://some_api" + id
    table = requests.get(url)
    return table
```

`test_get_table.py`:

```py
from get_table import get_table_name
from unittest.mock import patch
import unittest


class TestFetchTable(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('get_table.requests')
    def test_get_table_name(self, mock_requests):
        mock_requests.get.return_value = 'table_1'
        result = get_table_name('id1')
        self.assertEqual(result, 'table_1')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

unit test result with coverage report:

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
Name                                           Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/63306217/get_table.py            5      0   100%
src/stackoverflow/63306217/test_get_table.py      10      0   100%
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                             15      0   100%
```